# What is the difference between $\partial_\mu$ and $\partial^\mu$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, euler-lagrange-equation, convention, quantum-field-theory

I am taking quantum field theory this semester. There we use the Einstein Informalism. But I have never seen it before. I understood that if there are two letters on one letter, that this is a matrix, and if there is only one letter on it, that this is a vector. I am only confused about the derivations. There is one letter on top and one on the bottom. I suppose that this is as follows:

\begin{align} \partial_\mu L = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\mu}, \hspace{30pt} \partial^\mu L = \nabla L + \frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \end{align}

But now I have to derive the following:
\begin{align} L = \sqrt{\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu \phi}, \hspace{30pt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} = ?, \hspace{30pt} \partial_\mu \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} = ?   
\end{align}
And I am very unsure. Is $L$ still dependent on $\phi$? Because of the derivations this should disappear completely. But if I should derive it to $\partial_\mu \phi$, do I have to consider that $\partial^\mu \phi$ is dependent on $\partial_\mu \phi$? Theoretically $\partial^\mu \phi = (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^0}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^1}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^3})$. But how do I write this in the Einstein summation convention? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

$\partial_\mu$ is just shorthand for the partial derivative with respect to the corresponding coordinate:
$$
\partial_\mu:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}
$$
$\partial^\mu$ is just $\partial_\mu$ with an index raised; that is
$$
\partial^\mu:=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu
$$
Where $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse metric. Some authors write expressions exclusively in terms of $\partial_\mu$, writing the $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ factors explecitly. It might be instructive to do this in your situation.

Comment: Okay. Is that correct then?

\begin{align*}
        \frac{\partial(\partial^\mu\phi)}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\left(\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi\right) = \eta^{\mu\nu}\, \frac{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} = \eta^{\mu\nu}\,\delta_{\mu\nu}
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi_a)} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi}}\left(\partial^\mu\phi + \partial_\mu\phi\,\eta_{\mu\nu}\delta_{\mu\nu}\right)
    \end{align*}

Comment: No; your index manipulations are a bit off. They should read$$\frac{\partial(\partial^\mu\phi)}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}=\eta^{\mu\nu}\\\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}=\frac{1}{L}\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi$$

Comment: @Kajelad Sorry for commenting on an old post, but what is the significance of $\partial_mu$ vs $\partial^nu$? I understand the technical difference as you've described in your answer, but in practice why would want to raise the index on a partial derivative?